# Convert Int to Time with int value having hour and minute

Tags: sql-server

```
My values(int)     Expected
1107                11:07
1407                14:07
1202                00:02
```

My Sql Query

```
Declare @t int
SET @t=1102
Select LTrim(Stuff(Right(Convert(varchar(26), DateAdd(ss, '' + 60*((@t % 10000)/100) + @t%100, '19000101'), 109), 14), 9, 6, ' '))
```

**what i get**

12:11:02

**What i am expecting**

11:02

If there is any easier way ? 
Thank you for having a look.

Comment: thanks sorry to many tags i have edited my tag to Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Oh, you are on MSSql - leaving this here, if MySQL-Users come along in the future :)

The Idea should apply for MsSQL as well.

---

You should change your int-columns content, so it contains the *second of the day* i.e.

```
0      for 00:00:00
21.600 for 06:00:00
86.399 for 23:59:59
```

**MySQL:**
Then you could just use

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%H:%i')
```

and perform any maths required way easier.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/14236

**MsSQL:**
Then you could just use

```
 FORMAT(DATEADD(ss,seconds,0), 'HH:mm')
```

and perform any maths required way easier.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/2639

---

As your int-columns cant be changed - I would stick with the idea of using *seconds of the day* - and you can convert your representation, by multiplying the first 2 digits with 3600 and the last 2 digits with 60:

```
Declare @t int
SET @t=903
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(ss,
 LEFT(@t,LEN(@t)-2) * 3600 + 
 RIGHT(@t,2) * 60 
,0), 'HH:mm')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/2654

edit: Something simpliefied would work as well, as there is actually no conversion required (This just wouldn't return a `datetime` type, but a `string` type):

```
Declare @t int
SET @t=903
SELECT LEFT(@t,LEN(@t)-2) + ':' + RIGHT(@t,2)
```

But note the missing leading 0, when using this approach.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/2653

Comment: I do understand what you trying to do but how can i use it in above query.

Comment: My int column cannot be changed. Above values are just a representation of my table

Comment: Sorry it will not work for all cases for example :  902 , you are basically asking me to hard code first 2 and last 2 and putting a semicolon in the middle

Comment: @user3920526 Oh, i would have expected that has `0902` I've updated my answer to take this into account.

Comment: @user3920526 ps.: You should try to change that column-format, even if it's work. How is `00:07` stored? just `7`? That wouldn't work with any approach.